# How can I download only a certain bookshelf from Project Gutenberg?

Tags: web-applications, corpus

[This answer on webapps.SE](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/12312/96452) describes how to get English text files from Project Gutenberg.

My problem is that I don't want to download all ~40GB of ebook files since I need only a part: Is there a way to download just books from a specific bookshelf, e.g. the [Adventure bookshelf](https://www.gutenberg.org/wiki/Adventure_(Bookshelf)), combined with the language restriction (to English)?

[The official wiki](http://www.gutenberg.org/wiki/Gutenberg%3aInformation_About_Robot_Access_to_our_Pages) doesn't seem to have more information either.

Comment: This won't solve your problem, but you can download [the entire Science Fiction bookshelf as a torrent](http://www.gutenberg.org/cdproject/pgsfcd-032007.zip.torrent).

Comment: Thanks. I already looked for torrents, but I couldn't find torrents for other bookshelves.